# How can I run a GHCi statement in cabal v2-repl directly from command line?

Tags: haskell, cabal

How can I replicate `ghci -e "print 123"` in `cabal v2-repl`?

I've searched for "expression" or "statement" in `cabal v2-repl --help` with no luck.

Comment: `cabal v2-build && cabal v2-exec -- ghci -e "print 123"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use shell piping capabilities. See:

```
% cabal v2-repl <<< ':type zip'
...
λ zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
λ Leaving GHCi.
```

This `<<<` notation, in `sh` script interpreter, means that the quoted string is sent to the standard input of the command, followed by newline, then end of file.

There are other ways. For example, if you wish to supply more lines, you can use the so-called ["here-doc"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
% cabal repl <<EOF
:type zip
:type fst
EOF
```

The `<<<` notation is a shorthand for a one-line "here-doc".

In general, a program may know whether its standard input is a terminal *(assuming, live user)* or a file *(which `heredoc` pretends to be)*, and behave differently. But ordinarily it would work either way, and, if you can send things to its standard input, you can automate it.